# How to handle dynamic key in the response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have following response from my backend. Where the `"2018-03-18T03:30UTC"` is dynamic and it keep on change based on time. I want to fetch information inside the UTC date given. Any method to handle the dynamic key from the response.

```
 response =   {
      "id": 1252,
      "name": "S1",
      "description": "sss",
      "entity_type": "AGN",
      "media": [

      ],
      "event": [
        {
          "id": 1263,
          "name": "Agenda Debug Event",
          "media": [
            {
              "id": 1262,
              "entity_type": "MED",
              "media_type": "IMG",
              "media_element": "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/wizcard-image-bucket-dev/kiArBud7-alconf.jpeg",
              "media_iframe": "",
              "media_sub_type": "BNR"
            }
          ],
          "start": "2018-03-18T03:30:06Z",
          "end": "2018-03-19T13:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "entity_state": "PUB",
      "agenda_items": {
        "2018-03-19T03:30UTC": [
          {
            "id": 1261,
            "name": "s14",
            "description": "aseee",
            "start": "2018-03-19T12:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-19T13:29:29Z",
            "venue": "15",
            "speakers": [
              676
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 1265,
            "name": "s14",
            "description": "aseee",
            "start": "2018-03-19T12:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-19T13:29:29Z",
            "venue": "15",
            "speakers": [
              676
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 1272,
            "name": "s14",
            "description": "aseee",
            "start": "2018-03-19T12:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-19T13:29:29Z",
            "venue": "15",
            "speakers": [
              676
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          }
        ],
        "2018-03-18T03:30UTC": [
          {
            "id": 1253,
            "name": "seesion1",
            "description": "ascsds",
            "start": "2018-03-18T10:30:38Z",
            "end": "2018-03-18T12:30:38Z",
            "venue": "12",
            "speakers": [
              736
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 1256,
            "name": "S12",
            "description": "sss",
            "start": "2018-03-18T10:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-18T10:29:29Z",
            "venue": "",
            "speakers": [

            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 1258,
            "name": "s13",
            "description": "asddd",
            "start": "2018-03-18T11:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-18T12:29:29Z",
            "venue": "14",
            "speakers": [
              676
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 1260,
            "name": "s14",
            "description": "aseee",
            "start": "2018-03-18T12:29:29Z",
            "end": "2018-03-18T13:29:29Z",
            "venue": "15",
            "speakers": [
              676
            ],
            "media": [

            ],
            "agenda": 1252,
            "num_users": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "agenda_dates": [
        "2018-03-18T03:30UTC",
        "2018-03-19T03:30UTC"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: [angular.forEach](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/docs/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) seems like a pretty good candidate.

Comment: Look at the docs or one of hundreds of examples on the web. Research is your friend!

Answer (score 3):

This depends what do you mean by "handle dynamic keys".

And this is not really angular specific. If you just want to iterate through the entries you could use Object.keys() ([MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) for this.

```
Object.keys(response.agenda_items).forEach(key => {
    // do something here
})
```

Update:

As pointed out by Aleksey Solovey of course angular.forEach is also possible. It could look like this

```
 angular.forEach(response.agenda_items,(value, key) => { 
    /* do something here */ 
 }
```

The other Object functions like Object.entries() or Object.values() could also be used, depending on your usecase

Comment: something more readable, since it's angularjs -  `angular.forEach(response.agenda_items, function(res) { /* do something here */ })`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey of course thats true. I just try to use native JS whenever possible and avoid libs unless necessary. I will add your way to my answer